# Upgrade SQL Server 2000 engine

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, restore

I have SQL Server in which I need to upgrade and restore a `.bak` file

Server 1:

> Microsoft SQL Server  2000 - **8.00.194** (Intel X86)

And by requirements I need it to match Server 2:

> Microsoft SQL Server  2000 - **8.00.2040** (Intel X86)

I have the `SQL2000-KB899761-v8.00.2040-x86x64-ENU.exe`, but it says I need a previous update.

This version is too old and I can't figure where to start.

Actually what I really need is restore a `.bak` file from Server 2 and put it to Server 1.

I can't because it says:

> ... is not a valid Microsoft Tape Format

I can restore it within a 2008 Server. The issue is when I try to restore to the older Server 1.

Comment: Can you back up your Server 2 database to a .bak file on disk somewhere, then restore the .bak file to Server 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How to get the 8.00.194 (!!!!!!) server to 8.00.2040:**

You can [download Service Pack 4 (8.00.2039) from here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18290), which you will need to install before you can install the [8.00.2040 hotfix](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21788).

**How to restore a 2000 .bak to a 2008 server:**

You may need to clarify your actual requirements and clean up the question, but if you are trying to ultimately restore a SQL Server 2000 .bak file from server 2 to a SQL Server 2008 instance somewhere else, there is no reason to restore to server 1 first - just restore the .bak directly on the SQL Server 2008 instance (regardless of the source, 8.00.194 or 8.00.2040).

**How to resolve the invalid tape format message:**

You may have an invalid `RESTORE` statement, or you may have a corrupt backup. If the former, add the `RESTORE` statement to the question. If the latter, take a new backup (there are some tedious workarounds if you are restoring to 2005 or higher, but they include potentially allowing data loss). I don't believe this error message will be resolved simply by upgrading server 1. If `@@VERSION` were the issue (and it can be in some cases), you'd get a different error message than one about tape format.

Comment: Hi thanks.. I'm downloading the sp4 found it as accumulative upgrade, nice to be in the right way, will try it and inform.. what I mean by restore to a 2008 its actually that I can restore to it but not for another 2000. the .bak comes from the 8.00.2040 rev server

Comment: I accepted your answer due to upgraded was easy and correct. I just still can't figure why my 2008 server can use the backup and not the 2000 server